# Filename Regular Expression in PHP with Named Capture

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use a regex to match on a filename from the RecursiveDirectoryIterator which ends in .conf and then capture the filename and the directory (and optional sub directory it sits in).

Debugex says the capture works, but PHP is returning false, I need this to work on Windows and Linux.

I'm sure I've done something silly, any ideas what?

```
$indir = 'C:\Users\User\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\Dir4\models';
$filename = 'C:\Users\User\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\Dir4\models\product\subproduct\configuration-item.conf

// Or can be without sub product 
$filename = 'C:\Users\User\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\Dir4\models\product\configuration-item.conf


$regex = /** @lang RegExp */ "~" . addslashes($indir) . '\\*(?P<product>[^\\/]+)[\\/]*(?P<subproduct>[^\\/]*)[\\/](?P<file>.*)\.conf~';

$result = preg_match( $regex, $filename, $matches);
```

Comment: You might try `([\\/])(?P<product>[^/\r\n\\]+)\1(?P<subproduct>[^/\r\n\\]*)\1(?P<file>[^/\r\n\\]*)\.conf$` https://regex101.com/r/qUJxCn/1

Comment: would the function pathinfo() not be easier to use? https://www.php.net/pathinfo

Comment: Or with the whole part and the optional sub dir https://regex101.com/r/9P27zO/1

Comment: You are not getting any matches in the online tester - https://regex101.com/r/VfGbJw/1, so your regex is initially wrong. You need https://regex101.com/r/VfGbJw/2, see [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/kqXfi)

Comment: Ok, your only trouble is that you need 4 ``\``s to match a ``\``. You only used 2.

Comment: Ahh yes the problem was it needed 4 \, why does it need 4 it's a bit excessive?  Thank you others regex101 was also a lot more helpful than debugex